# I want to convert python script to Mac Executable file on windows

Tags: python, windows, macos

I am using Windows 7. I have recently completed a single python script and now I want to deliver it to my friend who uses Mac. He does not want to install Python; he needs an executable file of the Python script that can be easily run on Mac. I know we can convert Python script to Mac on Mac OS. But he is far from me, so I have to convert Python script to Mac OS application on my Windows 7.

How I can do that?

Comment: That's not so easy to solve with a simple command line. You could try to install a Mac OS virtual machine, try to install python inside it, and hope that it builds a Mac executable from there. I don't think it's possible to build one from windows. Only if your target is the Windows OS itself.

Comment: @CarlHR HR can i do it online by some way >

Comment: Maybe there is a framework that lets you build an executable for other systems, but you'd probably need to include tons of other modules (just like using Unity to build a C# or Javascript application to other operating systems).

Comment: I think it's way easier to simply tell your friend to install python inside his/her machine. I don't know if there are other ways to do build a Mac executable from windows. If you didn't found any tool online, I doubt there's any at all. The reason is because you'd need all the Mac binary files in order to make it work there.

Comment: @CarlHR he do not want to install python , he is saying that he need executable file for mac ,I am worried about that

Comment: If you're not using any GUI framework on your python script (such as tkinter, or pyqt) and your script only runs and print on terminal, you could use an online python interpreter to execute your script from there. Then both you and your friend would be able to run it.

Comment: i think P2app or cx freeze can convert python script to exe or .app according to our current Operating system. Is there any option where we can edit executable file extension

Comment: @CarlHR this is selenium script that checks wheter url is verified or not , it has 1 excel file along it where it reads urls and searches on Google and then checks wheter it is verified or not .After that it stores verified or not verified in front of that particular url .If i deploy it online like on heroku or somewhere else ,Then he would have edit excel file to enter urls again and again.

Comment: @CarlHR can you please suggest me one best interpreter for this project

Comment: Maybe you can deploy as a web server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create executable file on mac from python script developed on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220377/how-to-create-executable-file-on-mac-from-python-script-developed-on-windows)